# Is there a similar class as Rectangle in java me?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, midlet

So i just started programming mobile applications and when i wanted to use a Rectangle class i couldn't do it? What should i use instead of that class? I need something like that because i need to use intersects and intersection methods.

Answer (score 3):

You could just "borrow" the code from [java.awt.Rectangle](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Rectangle.java)

Comment: I am really sorry for my stupidity but when i try to do 
import java.awt.Rectangle;
java is underlined in red(using NetBeans).
Is there a trick to importing it?

Comment: Java ME is so cut down as not to include `Rectangle`. Because of this you can create your own Rectangle class using the code from `java.awt.Rectangle`. That's what I meant in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a simpler solution for intersects method(i guess you coudl write it yourself but why bother when you have the internet):

http://code.google.com/p/fram-j2me/source/browse/trunk/Farm/src/FrameWork/Rectangle.java?r=5